# facebook showing message for web URL 'page cannot be loaded'

Tags: branch.io

I was creating a link on Branch.IO for a blog post of our app. In redirects, I gave the web URL of the blog post for all - iOS, Android and Desktop.

When I share this URL on FB, then upon click, briefly I see toast message "This page cannot be loaded" and after a second, page loads in the fb's web browser. My concern is that my users will drop off on seeing that message and won't wait .

Is there a way to control this message?

Answer (score 0):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io)

Let me explain the default Branch link behavior
When you click on a Branch link and it opens via a browser (which supports URI schemes) say Chrome, Opera, Firefox etc. we try to open the App using URI schemes.

On Facebook:
When you click on a Branch link, it opens a captive web view and we try to open the App by firing URI schemes. Unfortunately, this is a limitation on Facebook's end where they cannot open the App using URI schemes (which results in the Toast message 'Page can't be loaded' to be displayed).

As a workaround, to prevent the Toast message from showing, when you create Branch links add `$always_deeplink` parameter and set it to `false`. If a 
 link has `$always_deeplink:false` parameter Branch will always fall back to your URL and not fire URI schemes.

PS: All Branch links which contain `$always_deeplink:false` when opened via a browser (e.g. Chrome) will fall back to the web URL you mentioned and not open the App, irrespective of whether the platform is Facebook or not.